# scan HTTP POST key-value pairs

Tags: java, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

In atypical http POST request,customer is appending some key-value pairs as querystrings and some key-value pairs as request payload.

Logically,everything should be treated as a query string .

How to detect in servlet layer that some of the key-value pairs are available in request paylaod of http post request?

If I use servlet filter,can i achieve it?Please help me on the same.Share necessary help websites to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think post appends as you say and the parameters are added to header. Get appends.

Comment: still we can append in POST too.